# Subversion Pre Commit Hook

Tags: svn, svn-hooks

Does anybody know whether it's possible via a Subversion pre-commit hook to check the **project name** that the commit is specified from?

I ideally want to use this to determine whether a commit message (and pattern) should be checked for that project.  The latter part here is fairly easy, but I only see a way to get the transaction id OR revision plus the repository for the commit.

http://code.google.com/p/subversion-pre-commit-hook/

Answer (score 1):

Subversion's pre-commit hooks give you the full path to the repository, the full filesystem path that is.  So if you can tell a project's name by its repository naming convention, you can use the pre-commit hook to get the project name.  But...Subversion itself has no concept of a project so for you to do this, your repository naming conventions would have to permit.

Answer (score 0):

Subversion passes this hook two parameters:

- the path to the root of the repository
- the transaction identifier

First parameter (indirectly)  will allow you to get project name